# Hacer consulta sql con variable php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta sql desde php con una variable que llega con un método GET, el problema es que no funciona, si en lugar de usar GET la declaro yo, si hace la consulta. Este es el código:

```
$fp = fopen("../../set.txt", "r");
    $linea = fgets($fp);
    $data = explode("&&;", $linea);
    $compid = $data[0];
    fclose($fp);

    $ccode = $_GET['cat'];

    $conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ianseo");
    mysqli_set_charset($conectar,"utf8");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE EvCode = '$ccode' AND EvTournament = '$compid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conectar,$sql);
    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $cat = $mostrar['EvEventName'];
    }
```

Si cambio $ccode = $_GET['cat']; por $ccode = "CSM"; si realiza la consulta correctamente y me muestra los resultados

Comment: Como estas mandando el valor?

Comment: Con un formulario usando el método GET a una página y en esta página lo vuelvo a pasar por la url

Comment: ¿Cómo la vuelves "a pasar por la url"?

Comment: Mediante un enlace

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código del formulario y de los enlaces donde pasas esa variable.

Comment: ¿Podrías hacerle un echo a la variable `$_GET['cat']` y ver que te imprime?

Comment: sospecho que la variable no está definida en el GET, a diferencia de lo que piensas. ¿Qué pasa si pones `if(!isset($_GET['cat'])) die("no existe cat!");`?